# How to show another swf file in the webview which showing a swf file?

Tags: cocoa

I want to show another swf file in the webview which showing a swf file, and I can get the path of the showing swf file , but when I drap another swf file to the webview which showing swf file , The swf file couldn't be opened, Why ? and some delegate methods of webview I forgot ? Someone can tell me ? Thanks!

I followed this example code:/Developer/Examples/Webket/MiniBrowser

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass WebView, and implement the dragging destination methods for that view.